# Improve client-side deserialization of SQL Server data stream

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sqldatareader

I am trying to improve the performance of large table reads from a remote SQL Server database. The test query is a simple `select * from [TableName]`.

For a load test of a million records, comprising about 70 MB in size, the response time bottleneck is not the server or the network, but the client application deserializing the stream output.

I have reproduced this issue in both SSMS as well as in a .Net client application using the `SqlDataReader` class. See the code snip below.

```
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
     var copy = new object[number_fields];
     reader.GetValues(copy);  
     // from here can parallelize processing of this copy data
}
```

If I iterate and discard the stream output (i.e., comment out `GetValues()`), the query completes quickly. The slowness appears by reintroducing this step. Likewise for SSMS.

I would be curious for an implementation or a pattern that would improve completion time to something faster than sequentially deserializing the stream output ?

A couple things:

1. Using asynchronous methods doesn't improve the read time, it only shifts the work to a background thread (which for this problem is not sufficient).
2. Iterating the `SqlDataReader` is stateful process. So far as I can tell there is no way to parallelize the work. Is someone familiar with an implementation that can ?
3. If I shard the original query into disjoint queries and execute in parallel, I substantially improve response time. However, this approach appears to get into MapReduce-like implementation issues. My hope is there is a simpler way to overcome this problem.

Comment: Using `SELECT *` will first query a system database to determine the columns that exist for that table. Explicitly naming all columns in the statement will eliminate this step and might improve speed when you have a lot of columns (i.e. rows from a system database to read).

Comment: @Gigabyte Valid point. Although small query optimizations may be possible, so far they are very small in comparison to the slowdown caused by deserializing the stream output.

Comment: @jharonfe, I think about the only thing you is attention to detail to make sure make sure the returned sql types deserialize efficiently. What sort of times are you experiencing?

Comment: @DanGuzman The load test of a million records, about 70MB in size, takes (1) 850 ms if iterated but not deserialized (2) 3200 ms if iterated and deserialized and (3) 1200 ms if sharded and processed in parallel.